# How do I make donut charts with facet_grid in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to make donut charts.

Only problem is they come out looking like this...

[image]

Here's my code

```
ggplot(
  diamonds,
  aes(
    x = cut,
    fill = color
  )
) +
  geom_bar(
    position = 'fill',
    stat = 'bin'
  ) +
  scale_y_continuous(
    labels = percent_format()
  ) +
  facet_grid(clarity ~ cut) + 
  coord_polar(theta = 'y')
```

How do I turn my charts from weird pies into circles with the same width?

Comment: Surely you can make a reproducible example, a **minimal** reproducible example, that is less than 85 lines of code and doesn't require going to some website to download an SPSS file? Please use built-in data that has similar structure, or quickly simulate data, or share your transformed data - the data in your plot - using `dput()`. [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/903061) for more tips on making a good example.

Comment: You may want to look into the `cut` function which is much nicer than nested `ifelse` statements for binning numeric data. Also `x %in% c("a", "b", "c")` is usually nicer than `x == "a" | x == "b" | x == "c"`.

Comment: @Gregor Thanks, I forgot about the stock datasets. Updated my PNG and code

Comment: @aosmith Replacing `x = cut` with `x = factor(1)` turns the rings into evenly-sized pies, but I want to make evenly-sized rings.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's a nice and tidy way to do it:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(data.table)

# get data, calculate quantities of interest
diam <- diamonds; setDT(diam) 
tabulated <- diam[, .N, by = .(cut, color, clarity)]

# plot
ggplot(tabulated, aes(x=2, y=N, fill=color)) +
  geom_bar(position = 'fill', stat = 'identity')  +
  facet_grid(clarity ~ cut) + 
  xlim(0.5, 2.5) +
  coord_polar(theta = 'y') + 
  labs(x=NULL, y=NULL)
```

[image]

Ok, how does this work? Let's look at your code - you get some plots that look like donuts but with varying hole sizes. Why is that? **It's helpful to 'unpie' the data and just look at the output as bars.** (I'm going to subset to just two rows of your facets for simplicity.)

```
ggplot(subset(diamonds, as.numeric(clarity) <=2), 
       aes(x = cut, fill = color)) +
  geom_bar(position = 'fill', stat = 'bin')  +
  facet_grid(clarity ~ cut)
```

[image]

You have a value mapped to X that isn't doing anything useful -- it's offsetting the bars, but since you are faceting on that variable each plot only has one stack of bars in it.

Yet when you add `coord_polar`, the plots with offset X values show up as donuts, while the plot with x=1 shows up as a pie That's because with `coord_polar`, the series of stacked bars are nested inside each other, and X=1 means the innermost 'coil'.

So, the solution begins with NOT mapping a real value to X. You can make X=1 for all plots, but then you'll get all pies, not donuts. What you want is a stacked bar, with some space before it on the x-axis (that’ll be the donut hole). You could do this by duplicating the data, so you have two sets stacked bars, then blanking out the first stack. That’s the answer I had up before, and it works (see edit history for details).

Hadley suggested a simpler solution via twitter, though, which I feel obligated to post for posterity: adjust the x limits to force some leading blank space on the x axis.

To begin, calculate the values you want (I'm using `data.table` for this):

```
library(data.table)
diam <- diamonds; setDT(diam)
tabulated <- diam[, .N, by = .(cut, color, clarity)]
```

Now plot, with some room before the stack of bars

[image]

There's the stacked bar chart you want, and all you have to do is add `coord_polar` (as done at the top of the post). You can play with the x limits to tune the donut/hole ratio to your liking.

Comment: This was exactly what I wanted! I just have a couple questions as an R noob. 1) What is going on in `diam[, .N, by = .(cut, color, clarity)]`? What does the comma, `by=` and `.` before the paranthesis mean?   2) In `plot_data[donutslice==1, N:=0]`, what does the `:` in `N:=0` mean?

Comment: That's `data.table` lingo.

Comment: Right, data.table lingo. The first thing just counts cases, grouped by the three variables. You could get something similar in base R with `aggregate(carat ~ cut + color + clarity, data=diamonds, FUN=length)` (but now the count column is named 'carat' instead of N). Learn data.table, though, it's great

Comment: The last thing is just data.table for assignment. base R: `plot_data$N[plot_data$donutslice==1] <- 0`, but the data.table version is much cleaner!